# verificar se coluna ja existe no banco

Tags: php

como posso verificar se um campo na minha coluna do banco ja existe? tentei assim porem nao esta retornando nada

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if(isset($_POST['adicionar'])&&$_POST['adicionar']=='adicionou'){

if(empty($_POST['nome'])){
    echo 'Nome está vazio.';
}else{

    $verificaDuplicados=$conn->prepare("SELECT `nome` FROM `noticias` WHERE `nome` = ".$_POST['nome']."") or die(mysqli_error());

    $verificaDuplicados->execute();

    $contaNoticia=$verificaDuplicados->rowCount($_POST['nome']);

    if($contaNoticia>=1){

       echo "ja existe";

    }else{
        echo "se a noticia nao existe faz o insert";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Tente user `or die(mysqli_error())` na frente das chamadas dos métodos `prepare`, `execute` e `rowCount`. Pode ser que mostre algo relacionado com o problema.

Comment: @RafaelMafra coloquei o `or die(mysqli_error())` no `select` ele esta ignorando a verificaçao se existe ou nao a coluna no banco

Comment: Não é algum problema na sintax do seu código? Está faltando fechar um bracket do primeiro `if`.

Comment: @RafaelMafra eu esqueci de fechar a chave que da açao no botao pra postar o codigo aqui, verifiquei e todas as chaves estao fechadas corretamente

Comment: Tente fechar o valor da query com aspas simples para formar uma string: `'".$_POST['nome']."'"`

Comment: @RafaelMafra deu certo, obrigado maninho